# WSO2 API Manager - How to configure WSO2 Analytics Server with 2 Instances of API Manager Up and Running

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm using 2 instances of WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 within the same node. (one instance as a gateway which is exposed to DMZ)

I tried to configure the WSO2 Analytics Server and came up with the following concern.

1. Since the gateway is already up and running with an offset of 1, how should I be setting the offset in the Analytics Server in order to get it to work? In the documentation, I noticed this: "By default, WSO2 API Manager has a port offset of 0 (no port offset) and WSO2 API Manager Analytics has an offset of 1. Therefore, this guide assumes that you do not have any other carbon servers running on the same machine with port offsets of 0 or 1." If so how should I proceed with configuring the Analytics Server?
2. Should I configure 2 Analytics Servers for both instances?

Any guidance for these concerns is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure a different port offset for the analytics server. You can configure the offset in `<ANALYTICS_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml`. Set the offset as  `<Offset>2</Offset>`. By configuring this, Your analytics server can be up in a different port (APIM_PORT+2).
2. Only one instance of Analytics is enough. Point all your APIM instances to the analytics server you configured.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this. I assumed that the offset should always be +1 from the offset of the instance of that particular API Manager.

Comment: After doing this, multiple lines of the following error could be seen in the logs of the gateway instance.  ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker}